# Como fazer upload de imagens para uma pasta usando o ASP Clássico?

Tags: html, asp

Existe algum script para ASP Clássico para que eu consiga fazer upload de uma imagem para uma pasta.

Ex: clico em um botão, carrego a imagem, clico para fazer upload e vai para uma pasta por exemplo: `C:\ASP\sistema\imagens`.

Comment: Pelo que me parece apenas queres escolher a pasta de destino. Encontrei isto, dá uma olhadela. 
http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iu7/uploading-folders-in-aspnet.htm

Comment: ASP clássico é totalmente diferente de ASP.NET @CesarMiguel, acho que seu comentário não vai ajudar o rapaz...

Comment: Ah okok, não sabia :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ASP clássico você não tem como acessar o método `Request.Form` diretamente quando está recebendo de um POST com tipo `multipart/form-data`, então para interpretar os dados, é necessário fazer um parse das informações enviadas, um projeto que pode lhe ajudar é o [Pure ASP Upload](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19297/Pure-ASP-File-Upload.htm) que lhe ajudará nesta tarefa, ou então você pode instalar componentes no seu servidor como o [ASP Upload](http://www.aspupload.com/) que vai lhe adicionar uma classe que permite interpretar esse tipo de form e salvar seu conteúdo no servidor.

Este código é escrito em VB5, então se seu servidor não estiver com VB atualizado, você precisará atualiza-lo para funcionar.

Código fonte do Pure ASP Upload:

```
<%
'***************************************
' File:   Upload.asp
' Author: Jacob "Beezle" Gilley
' Email:  avis7@airmail.net
' Date:   12/07/2000
' Comments: The code for the Upload, CByteString, 
'           CWideString subroutines was originally 
'           written by Philippe Collignon...or so 
'           he claims. Also, I am not responsible
'           for any ill effects this script may
'           cause and provide this script "AS IS".
'           Enjoy!
'****************************************

Class FileUploader
    Public  Files
    Private mcolFormElem

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set Files = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set mcolFormElem = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        If IsObject(Files) Then
            Files.RemoveAll()
            Set Files = Nothing
        End If
        If IsObject(mcolFormElem) Then
            mcolFormElem.RemoveAll()
            Set mcolFormElem = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Property Get Form(sIndex)
        Form = ""
        If mcolFormElem.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) Then Form = mcolFormElem.Item(LCase(sIndex))
    End Property

    Public Default Sub Upload()
        Dim biData, sInputName
        Dim nPosBegin, nPosEnd, nPos, vDataBounds, nDataBoundPos
        Dim nPosFile, nPosBound

        biData = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)
        nPosBegin = 1
        nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, CByteString(Chr(13)))

        If (nPosEnd-nPosBegin) <= 0 Then Exit Sub

        vDataBounds = MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin)
        nDataBoundPos = InstrB(1, biData, vDataBounds)

        Do Until nDataBoundPos = InstrB(biData, vDataBounds & CByteString("--"))

            nPos = InstrB(nDataBoundPos, biData, CByteString("Content-Disposition"))
            nPos = InstrB(nPos, biData, CByteString("name="))
            nPosBegin = nPos + 6
            nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, CByteString(Chr(34)))
            sInputName = CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))
            nPosFile = InstrB(nDataBoundPos, biData, CByteString("filename="))
            nPosBound = InstrB(nPosEnd, biData, vDataBounds)

            If nPosFile <> 0 And  nPosFile < nPosBound Then
                Dim oUploadFile, sFileName
                Set oUploadFile = New UploadedFile

                nPosBegin = nPosFile + 10
                nPosEnd =  InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, CByteString(Chr(34)))
                sFileName = CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))
                oUploadFile.FileName = Right(sFileName, Len(sFileName)-InStrRev(sFileName, "\"))

                nPos = InstrB(nPosEnd, biData, CByteString("Content-Type:"))
                nPosBegin = nPos + 14
                nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, CByteString(Chr(13)))

                oUploadFile.ContentType = CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))

                nPosBegin = nPosEnd+4
                nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, vDataBounds) - 2
                oUploadFile.FileData = MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin)

                If oUploadFile.FileSize > 0 Then Files.Add LCase(sInputName), oUploadFile
            Else
                nPos = InstrB(nPos, biData, CByteString(Chr(13)))
                nPosBegin = nPos + 4
                nPosEnd = InstrB(nPosBegin, biData, vDataBounds) - 2
                If Not mcolFormElem.Exists(LCase(sInputName)) Then mcolFormElem.Add LCase(sInputName), CWideString(MidB(biData, nPosBegin, nPosEnd-nPosBegin))
            End If

            nDataBoundPos = InstrB(nDataBoundPos + LenB(vDataBounds), biData, vDataBounds)
        Loop
    End Sub

    'String to byte string conversion
    Private Function CByteString(sString)
        Dim nIndex
        For nIndex = 1 to Len(sString)
           CByteString = CByteString & ChrB(AscB(Mid(sString,nIndex,1)))
        Next
    End Function

    'Byte string to string conversion
    Private Function CWideString(bsString)
        Dim nIndex
        CWideString =""
        For nIndex = 1 to LenB(bsString)
           CWideString = CWideString & Chr(AscB(MidB(bsString,nIndex,1))) 
        Next
    End Function
End Class

Class UploadedFile
    Public ContentType
    Public FileName
    Public FileData

    Public Property Get FileSize()
        FileSize = LenB(FileData)
    End Property

    Public Sub SaveToDisk(sPath)
        Dim oFS, oFile
        Dim nIndex

        If sPath = "" Or FileName = "" Then Exit Sub
        If Mid(sPath, Len(sPath)) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

        Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not oFS.FolderExists(sPath) Then Exit Sub

        Set oFile = oFS.CreateTextFile(sPath & FileName, True)

        For nIndex = 1 to LenB(FileData)
            oFile.Write Chr(AscB(MidB(FileData,nIndex,1)))
        Next

        oFile.Close
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveToDatabase(ByRef oField)
        If LenB(FileData) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        If IsObject(oField) Then
            oField.AppendChunk FileData
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
%>
```

**Exemplo de uso:**

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%Option Explicit%>
<!-- #include file="upload.asp" -->
<%

'NOTE - YOU MUST HAVE VBSCRIPT v5.0 INSTALLED ON YOUR WEB SERVER
'      FOR THIS LIBRARY TO FUNCTION CORRECTLY. YOU CAN OBTAIN IT
'      FREE FROM MICROSOFT WHEN YOU INSTALL INTERNET EXPLORER 5.0
'      OR LATER.


' Create the FileUploader
Dim Uploader, File
Set Uploader = New FileUploader

' This starts the upload process
Uploader.Upload()

'******************************************
' Use [FileUploader object].Form to access 
' additional form variables submitted with
' the file upload(s). (used below)
'******************************************
Response.Write "<b>Thank you for your upload " & Uploader.Form("fullname") & "</b><br>"

' Check if any files were uploaded
If Uploader.Files.Count = 0 Then
    Response.Write "File(s) not uploaded."
Else
    ' Loop through the uploaded files
    For Each File In Uploader.Files.Items

        ' Check where the user wants to save the file
        If Uploader.Form("saveto") = "disk" Then

            ' Save the file
            File.SaveToDisk "E:\UploadedFiles\"

        ElseIf Uploader.Form("saveto") = "database" Then

            ' Open the table you are saving the file to
            Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            RS.Open "MyUploadTable", "CONNECT STRING OR ADO.Connection", 2, 2
            RS.AddNew ' create a new record

            RS("filename")    = File.FileName
            RS("filesize")    = File.FileSize
            RS("contenttype") = File.ContentType

            ' Save the file to the database
            File.SaveToDatabase RS("filedata")

            ' Commit the changes and close
            RS.Update
            RS.Close
        End If

        ' Output the file details to the browser
        Response.Write "File Uploaded: " & File.FileName & "<br>"
        Response.Write "Size: " & File.FileSize & " bytes<br>"
        Response.Write "Type: " & File.ContentType & "<br><br>"
    Next
End If

%>
```

**HTML do Exemplo:**

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="uploadexmple.asp">
    <TABLE BORDER=0>
    <tr><td><b>Enter your fullname:</b><br><INPUT TYPE=TEXT SIZE=40 NAME="FULLNAME"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Select a file to upload:</b><br><INPUT TYPE=FILE SIZE=50 NAME="FILE1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Save To:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Disk&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="saveto" value="disk" checked>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Database&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="saveto" value="database">
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center"><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Upload!"></td></tr>
    </TABLE>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Então isso significa que eu não vou conseguir usar um AJAX por exemplo para fazer esse action?

Comment: @cardosoluizjr sim, você pode utilizar o AJAX, neste caso é o lado do cliente que vai criar uma requisição a ser enviada pro seu servidor, se você adicionar propriedades que façam essa requisição ser interpretada como um `POST` com `multipart/form-data`, o seu servidor irá aceitar, utilizando um código como o descrito ou um componente (que pode lhe dar mais possibilidades) você irá fazer upload e salvar os arquivos na pasta desejada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a classe [clsUpload](http://www.bookwolf.com/Wolf/lib/clsUpload.asp).

Depois que você der um include nela, você pode simplesmente fazer assim:

**ASP:**

```
Dim objUpload 
Dim strArquivo, strCaminho

Set objUpload = New clsUpload
strArquivo= objUpload.Fields("file").FileName
strCaminho= "C:/ASP/sistema/imagens/" & strFile

objUpload("file").SaveAs strCaminho
Set objUpload = Nothing
```

**HTML:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="clsUpload.asp">
  <div>Enviar arquivo: </div>
  <div>
    <input type="file" NAME="file"> 
    <input type="button" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
  </div>
</form>
```

Vi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190305/how-to-upload-files-with-asp-classic).

Comment: Essa resposta funcionou também!